# ExpressJS router getting different request params compared to app.use

Tags: node.js, express

If I go to https://example.com/random

```
const router = express.Router();
router.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.params);
});
app.use("*", router);
```

I get

> { '0': '/' }

as output where as if I do

```
app.use("*", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.params);
});
```

I get as expected

> { '0': '/random' }

Is this the expected behavior or some kind of bug or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your first example you are intending for all requests to use the `router` so you should do this:

```
const router = express.Router();
router.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.params);
});
app.use("/", router);
```

This tells the app to use `router` for anything starting with `/` (the root) and will send `/random` to your `get` as expected.

The reason you got what you saw is that using `app.use("*",router)` means "take anything as the root and send along to `router`. In the case of "/random" it treated it as the root entirely and sent everything after it to the router.

For example, if instead you said `app.use('/random',router)` then and then tried this url:

```
http://example.com/random/hello/there
```

You would see the `get` be called with `/hello/there` (ie, everything *after* the match string).